# Not showing correct info PHP and Oracle query

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My question is about an Oracle database which i can connect with PHP. With the same query using SQL Developer i've got this:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

But in PHP:

```
$tsql= "select orden, fase, maquina_id, DescMaterial, dhsalida, scg_MaterialesLotes.lote, scg_MaterialesLotes.lotecli from scg_fases inner join scg_materiales on scg_fases.IdBoletin = scg_Materiales.IdBoletin inner join scg_MaterialesLotes on scg_Materiales.IdMatOf = scg_MaterialesLotes.IdMatOF";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);  

if ( $stmt )    
{ 
  ?>

  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    $orden = $row["orden"];
    $fase = $row["fase"];
    $puesto = $row["maquina_id"];
    $art = $row["CodMaterial"];
    $desc = $row["DescMaterial"];
    $fecha = $row["dhsalida"];
    $lote = $row["scg_MaterialesLotes.lote"];
    $loteCli = $row["scg_MaterialesLotes.lotecli"];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $orden . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $fase . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $puesto . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $art . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $desc . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $fecha . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $lote . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $loteCli . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }

  ?>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  <?php
}     
else     
{    
  echo "Submission unsuccessful.";
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));    
} 

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);    
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

Using browser it shows:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Why i can't show the same info? Where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: sqlsrv_fetch_array isn't that to use against sqlserver? oracle driver uses OCI_FETCH_ARRAY http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Add `CodMaterial` field to your query** You're not including the field `CodMaterial` in your query, so this line:

`$art = $row["CodMaterial"];`

Does nothing. So you can either add this field to the long list of fields in your query, or just use `SELECT * FROM...` to retrieve every field.

**2) Don't use tablename.columnname in your query results rows** When you query for `scg_MaterialesLotes.lote` for example, the resulting attribute will be called `lote`, so instead of having this in your PHP code:

`$lote = $row["scg_MaterialesLotes.lote"];`

Use this:

`$lote = $row["lote"];`

Do the same for `scg_MaterialesLotes.lotecli`

**3) Echo `$fecha` as a string, at the moment is an object of type** Instead of using:

`echo "<td align=center>" . $fecha . "</td>";`

Use this instead:

`echo "<td align=center>" . ($fecha ? $fecha->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") : ""). "</td>";`

Comment: Ok, i made the changes and now it's fixed the first row, but it stops in the second row in the dhsalida field (it's a date field), in the first row this field is empty but in the second no. It seems that it's a problem with dates...

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump($fecha)`?

Comment: Result for each row:  NULL < >object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-12 10:12:55.557000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } < >object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-12 10:20:22.547000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } < >object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-12 11:41:04.663000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } < >NULL....

Comment: @marcss There, `$fecha` is an object. I edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: Now don't stop at the date field, but is not showing anything in the field

Comment: @marcss Try `$fecha->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")` as it's in the updated answer.

Comment: The same problem, using format it stops at the date field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179456/discussion-between-ammopt-and-marcss).